# MYSQL trigger syntax - missing semicolon

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm relatively new to MYSQL from an MS SQL background. Can someone please point out why I'm getting syntax errors here please? I'm sure I've done something very obviously wrong but I just can't see it:

I'm getting a missing semicolon syntax error on line 8:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_InsertProductWatchListPriceHistory
AFTER UPDATE
ON ProductWatchlist FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO ProductWatchListPriceHistory 
(ProductWatchlistID,Price) 
VALUES  
(ProductWatchlistID,New.ProductPrice);
END;
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to change your default delimiter to something else than `;`. Otherwise your definition ends at the first `;` which would make it incomplete.

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER trg_InsertProductWatchListPriceHistory
AFTER UPDATE
ON ProductWatchlist FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO ProductWatchListPriceHistory (ProductWatchlistID, Price) 
   VALUES (New.ProductWatchlistID, New.ProductPrice);
END
|
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks! I suspected it might be something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this bash [script](https://github.com/vaibs2987/mysql-trigger) for generating the update trigger.
This script will require the database name and table names.
While using this script please update the username and password.

Comment: Thanks for the effort in creating that script, but this doesn't answer the original question.

Answer (score 1):

If using MySQL Workbench then  Editor's create trigger under table design options  should be used to avoid changing delimiters before and after.